# PolyAnalyst: How is the keywords tab of the taxonomy calculated?

Tags: nlp, keyword

In the taxonomy is a keywords tab that shows the keywords for that particular category created and defined by a PDL expression. If I create a subset of that same category and run a keyword extraction node on it, then I never see the same results as the taxonomy's list of keywords. Why is that? How are they different if the approach appears to be the same and they both appear to be using the same statistics dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation for the Keywords tab in a Taxonomy node is done for the words in the particular category relative to the entire dataset, while the calculation in a Keyword Extraction node following a Taxonomy Subset node is done for these same words only relative to the corresponding subset, and hence the difference.

In other words, by removing the subset from the taxonomy node you are removing some context that provides information to the keyword calculation.